# C# Linq NULLReferenceException when searching on value inside list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString)
{
    IEnumerable<Satellites_> chan_name = from m in db.Satellites_ select m;

    List<Satellites_> satlist = chan_name.ToList<Satellites_>();

    var engname = searchString.Split(",".ToCharArray());

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        //the error from s.satName_En it's always have null value 
        // and i'm make sure that the list contains the value enter image description here
        var temp = chan_name.Where(s => s.satName_En.Equals(engname[0])).ToList<Satellites_>();

        return PartialView("_SearchIndex", temp);
    }

    return PartialView("_SearchIndex", engname);
}
```

Comment: it looks like engname[0] doesn't exist (or is null). check your input string searchString. Also I think you have to use single quotes when splitting by a single char.

Comment: engname[0] it's contains two string but the problem in s.satName_En 
always have a null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating through all the records in `Satellites`. If any records have a `null` value in that field, you'll get an exception.

If you want to ignore any records with a `null` value, try omitting them:

```
var temp = chan_name.Where(s => s.satName_En != null
                                && s.satName_En.Equals(engname[0])).ToList();
```